# Deploy Telegram Bot (in Kotlin) to cloud service

Tags: kotlin, deployment, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I started to write a telegram bot using `Kotlin`, with these APIs:

https://github.com/kotlin-telegram-bot/kotlin-telegram-bot

I have a project inside `IntelliJ IDEA`, everything works well: when I run the code locally, program is in polling to listen to my requests. Also in telegram client the bot responses are very smooth.

This is the example provided on *GitHub*

`Main.kt`

```
fun main() {
    val bot = bot {
        token = "YOUR_API_KEY"
        dispatch {
            command("start") {
                val result = bot.sendMessage(chatId = ChatId.fromId(message.chat.id), text = "Hi there!")
                result.fold({
                    // do something here with the response
                },{
                    // do something with the error 
                })
            }
        }
    }
    bot.startPolling()
}
```

How can I deploy the code to a cloud server and leave it running? And which provider should I choose between **Amazon AWS**, **Microsoft Azure** and **Google Cloud** to easily achieve my goal (mainly for testing purposes, so only free plans)?

Reading other questions, I have found solutions using `Python` only...may I use the same approach?

Answer (score 1):

Common solution is to wrap your application in Docker container and then deploy it. See [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/) on how to deploy Docker containers to ECS